# A proof by strong induction that $a_n\le3^n$ where $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction, recurrence-relations

I am not sure whether this is right. Can anyone verify, whether this proof is valid? Thanks!

[image]
[image]

> Define a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\ge0}$ as follows:
>   $$a_0=1,\qquad,a_1=3,\qquad,a_2=9,\qquad,a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}\text{ for }n\ge3.$$
>   Prove that for any positive integer $n$, $a_n\le3^n$.

---

> *Proof.* Let $P(n)$: $a_n\le 3^n$, $n$ is a non-negative integer.
>
> *(i) Base case:*
>
> - Consider when $n=0$. LHS$=a_0=1$, RHS=$3^0=1$ $\therefore$ LHS$\le$RHS, then $P(0)$ holds.
> - Consider when $n=1$. LHS$=a_1=3$, RHS=$3^1=3$ $\therefore$ LHS$\le$RHS, then $P(1)$ holds.
> - Consider when $n=1$. LHS$=a_2=9$, RHS=$3^2=9$ $\therefore$ LHS$\le$RHS, then $P(2)$ holds.
>
> *(ii) Inductive case:*
>   Assume $P(i)$ is true for $0 \le i \le k$, $k\ge2$.
>
> *(iii) Inductive conclusion:* Consider $n=k+1$.
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> \mathrm{LHS}=a_{k+1}&=a_k+a_{k-1}+a_{k-2} \qquad\text{(by definition, since $k\ge 2$)}\\
>                     &\le 3^k+3^{k-1}+3^{k-2} \qquad\text{(by Induction Hypothesis)}\\
>                     &=3^k(3^{-1}+3^{-2}+3^{-3})\\
>                     &=3^k\left(\frac13+\frac19+\frac1{27}\right)\\
>                     &=\frac{13}{27} 3^k\\
>                     &\le 3^{k+1} = \mathrm{RHS}
> \end{align*}
> $$
>   Therefore, by the Principle of Strong Induction, $P(n)$ is true for all non-negative positive integers $n$.

Comment: I have added text version. It has some advantages - for example images are no help when searching and also you can easily edit the text, for an image you would have to do a new scan/photo. But I do appreciate that you have provided a picture in good quality and very readable (very nice handwriting.) I also appreciate that you have included your own solution. +1 from me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice write-up; looks great! Perhaps a slightly slicker way of doing the induction step (and probably what the problem intended you to do) is to observe that:
\begin{align*}
3^k + 3^{k-1} + 3^{k-2}
&< 3^k + (3)3^{k-1} + (3^2)3^{k-2} \\
&= 3^k + 3^k + 3^k \\
&= 3(3^k) \\
&= 3^{k+1}
\end{align*}